# RPM and ISO , package installation

Tags: linux, rhel, package-management, rpm

I am tying to install package `rpm -ivh binutils-2.23.52.0.1-12.el7.x86_64,` I mounted the ISO image `mount -t iso9660 -o loop /linux71_iso/RHEL-7.1-20150219.1-Server-x86_64-dvd1.iso /iso_mount`

Now I would like query  iso for binutils-2.23.52.0.1-12.el7.x86_64.rpm and install it.

Answer (score 1):

To find it:

```
find /iso_mount binutils-2.23.52.0.1-12.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

To find and install it:

```
rpm -ivh $(find /iso_mount binutils-2.23.52.0.1-12.el7.x86_64.rpm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not install it from the repo? So you will have the latest version.

`yum install binutils`

You will probably want to use `yum` instead of `rpm`. `yum` does dependency resolving and can install dependencies for you.